# How to write code that performs actions based on what type is

Tags: java, methods, types

Please bear with me as I struggle through this phrasing this question. So let's say I have a user-defined type called "UserType" and that this type has 4 values: North, South, East, and West.

```
public enum UserType {
    NORTH, SOUTH, EAST, WEST
}
```

Then, I want to write a method statement in a different class that will increase the value of two variables based on the type. For example,

```
public class direction {
    private int peopleWhoGoNorth;
    private int peopleWhoGoSouth;
```

so peopleWhoGoNorth should track the number of people who go North every time the following method is called:

```
public void whichWay(UserType type) {
        }
```

I'm wondering how I would create a statement in between the brackets that would basically say: if the type is North, add 1 to peopleWhoGoNorth and if the type is South, add 1 to peopleWhoGoSouth. I'm guessing an if/else statement should do it, but I'm not sure how the syntax would work. Is the following OK?

```
public void whichWay (UserType type){
    if (UserType = NORTH){peopleWhoGoNorth = peopleWhoGoNorth + 1);
    if (UserType = SOUTH){peopleWhoGoSouth = peopleWhoGoSouth + 1);
    }
```

Please let me know if there is any way I can clarify the question.

Comment: `if ( UserType == North )`...

Comment: For starters, those `if` statements at the end should be using `==` and not `=`... e.g. `if (UserType == NORTH) [...]`

Comment: The following *approach* is OK (once operator is fixed). There are three kinds of basic dispatches to "perform action based on type/value": conditionals (as shown), lookup tables, and polymorphism.

Comment: I'm getting errors that state that both UserType and North cannot be resolved to a variable, however...

Comment: Once you fix the `==` (so it is not taken as an assignment) and use the *type-qualified name* of the enumeration value (eg. `UserType.NORTH`) then the errors - which specifically relates to Java trying to treat the tokens as variables.

Comment: suggestion from Scott Hunter + no '{' after if statement as it is only one statement..

Comment: @Prasad Counter suggestion: *always* use braces, *except* for on-a-single-line `throw` or `return`. As otherwise 'adding a new line' in a conditional (without braces) takes some thoughts or it can silently corrupt a program.

Answer (score 4):

You can use a switch for enums:

```
public void whichWay (UserType type){
  switch (type) {
    case NORTH:
      peopleWhoGoNorth++;
      break;
    case SOUTH:
      peopleWhoGoSouth++;
      break;
    default:
      throw new IllegalArgumentException();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to use `==`: `if (type == NORTH)`.

You can also use a `switch` statement:

```
switch(type) {
  case NORTH: 
    peopleWhoGoNorth++;
    break;
  case SOUTH: 
    peopleWhoGoSouth++;
    break;
  default: // do nothing
}
```

Comment: This will cause both `peopleWhoGoNorth` and `peopleWhoGoSouth` to be incremented if `type` is `NORTH` due to the lack of `break` statements.

Comment: missing break; statement

Comment: is there a way to do nothing in the case of EAST and WEST? not even throw an exception, just do nothing?

Answer (score 2):

You can simply compare your `type` with the types you wanna check for.

```
public void whichWay(UserType type) {
    if (type == UserType.NORTH) {
        //Execute code
    }
    //Other types analog
}
```

or you can use a switch statement:

```
public void whichWay(UserType type) {
    switch (type) {
        case NORTH:
            //Execute code
            break;
        //Other types analog
        default:
    }
}
```

Comment: Oops, sorry. I was actively editing at the same time. It's fixed again.

Answer (score 0):

I would say that you are on the correct track.

Consider just the method "whichWay":

```
public void whichWay(UserType type) {
    if(type == UserType.NORTH) { peopleWhoGoNorth++; }
    else if(type == UserType.SOUTH) { peopleWhoGoSouth++; }
}
```

Comment: Well, considering OP tagged his question Java, I'm pretty sure he's working in Java ;)

Answer (score 0):

`switch` and `if-else` has been covered, but you could also use a `Map` to contain the count of those who have gone in a given direction.

```
public enum UserType {
    NORTH, SOUTH, EAST, WEST
}

public class Example{
    private final Map<UserType,Integer> typeMap = new HashMap<>();

    public void whichWay(UserType type){
        int val = typeMap.getOrDefault(type,0);
        typeMap.put(type,val++);
    }
}
```

Of course, you would need to add methods to get those values in order to make this useful.

Answer (score 0):

One alternative would be to use [an EnumMap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/EnumMap.html):

```
private final EnumMap<UserType, Integer> counter = new EnumMap<> (UserType.class);
{
  for (UserType u : UserType.values()) counter.put(u, 0);
}

public void whichWay (UserType type){
  counter.put(type, counter.get(type) + 1);
}
```

Or with Java 8:

```
private final EnumMap<UserType, Integer> counter = new EnumMap<> (UserType.class);

public void whichWay (UserType type){
  counter.compute(type, (u, i) -> i == null ? 0 : i + 1);
}
```

(Note: this is not thread safe)